# Redirect url for Google OAuth Android

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth, xamarin.android, google-oauth

Never really worked with OAuth, trying to implement it now, I want to get access token and profile data from google and facebook. Using Xamarin.Auth.

With Facebook there're no problems, I specify "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" as redirect url and after I login it goes back to the activity I was before.

However with Google it's not as smooth - couldn't find any similar to facebook login success pages, somewhere found suggestion to use "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me" - added it to redirect url white list, however after sign in I would get `"Redirect_url_mismatch" A native application: application name`according to their documentation I should use "my.package.name:" and again I added that to redirect url white list, attempted to sign in, this time after sign in screen I get to second screen where I need to confirm read permissions and after that I get very short error something like "com.my.package:/?oauthparameterX=value1...." and get redirected to permission screen again.

Here's my complete OAuth2Authenticator:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: SocialIds.GooglePlusId,
            clientSecret: SocialIds.GooglePlusSecret,
            scope: OAuthUrl.GoogleScope,
            authorizeUrl: new Uri(OAuthUrl.GoogleAuthorize),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"),
            accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
            getUsernameAsync: null);
            auth.AllowCancel = false;
```

urls:

```
public static string GoogleAuthorize = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
public static string GoogleScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
public static string GoogleRedirect = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me";
public static string GoogleUserInfo = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={0}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above listed code, you are not giving the redirect uri instead you are giving the scope of google api. The purpose of redirect uri is to recieve the response from google api after authorization. The response should be a **code**. This response code is used for accessing the **access_token,refresh_token, id_token etc**. So you have to recieve this code in your project side.For this purpose , the redirect uri is used.
Go to your google console, create project, add credentials, then you will be redirect to a page conatains,

[image]

You can find the authorized redirect url. Give the url , then configure your code with new redirect url . Everything will be fine after this.

Comment: Hi, could you check this question, I have a similar problem on redirecting while data is beeing fetched (i dont know what page to use for that): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882563/redirect-uri-for-google-api-in-xamarin-app-to-show-loading-page

Comment: What URL should I give though? In case of a mobile app there's no URL to redirect to because it's not a webapp. Probably I'm missing something, I'm coming from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074196/how-to-configure-google-oauth-to-redirect-to-a-non-https-custom-url-for-cross