# How to configure Google OAuth to redirect to a non https custom URL? (for cross platform mobile app)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, cross-platform, google-fit

When I use OAuth in cross platform mobile app (like Apache Cordova) I cannot specify a server URL as a redirect URL since the execution should return to the mobile device, not to a webapp hosted on a server. It's also observed that if https protocol would be used it tends to work less reliably with some mobile browsers than custom made-up protocol.

For example for Strava I use "stravacordova://redirect/" as a redirect URL, for SUUNTO I use "suuntocordova://redirect/" and similarly for Under Armour and Training Peaks. Now as I try to add integration for Google Fit, I cannot follow this pattern. I'm stuck.

[image]

Is there any way to circumnavigate this?

Comment: I am also hitting the same error. The message is saying that you can't use an IP address in the Authorized Redirect URI. You'll need a public verified domain or you can use any subdomains or pages for your app. Perhaps try to use an external public valid dns name and set up a redirect to your server.

Comment: @ilovesyntax That's a different use-case than mine. You at least have a back-end server, although only with an IP address. However in case of a mobile app authentication I want the user to be authenticated on the device itself, and no back-end exists. This works fine with Strava, SUUNTO, Training Peaks and some other OAuths as I described. You have the option to obtain a DNS name, in case of my mobile app that's not possible, every mobile installation has a different device.

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438445/redirect-url-for-google-oauth-android

Comment: So in this entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367795/oauth-redirect-uri-alternatives-for-non-web-applications I use the Option 1 (custom scheme registered in the Android manifest). Maybe I should do Option 2 somehow? That would be less seamless for the user, I'm not sure if I can leverage the landing website for this.