# redirect_uri for Google API in Xamarin App to show loading page

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, google-api, google-oauth

I have working Xamarin Forms app where user can login with their Google account. For redirect uri I have assigned just `www.google.com`:

```
var requestUrl =
          
            "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
            + "?code=" + code
            + "&client_id=" + ClientId
            + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret
            + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri
            + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
```

What else could I provide as redirect link? Is there any loading/waiting page for that? Because now user sees google main page while information is being fetched.

Comment: This case: [Redirect url for Google OAuth Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438445/redirect-url-for-google-oauth-android) could be helpful to you.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT thanks. But it doesnt answer my question. That answer shows where to register a link in Google API developer console. But I want to know what link should I register to show loading page. Now it shows just Google.com page for me because thats what I have registered to show.

Comment: But it doesnt look good because user might not understand what is happening, why they see google page. Because log in process might sometimes take some time (if internet is slower for example)

Comment: I get your mean for now.

Comment: What type of client id did you create?  authorization_code is normally used for web applications in this case the redirect uri is the location of the web page that can handle your authorization response.  Google.com is not your website you wont be able to verfy that domain.